# нужно указывать ключевое слово this или не нужно?

Tags: dart

Нужно указывать ключевое слово **this** или не нужно? Подскажите. Спасибо.

```
void main() {
 Atom a = Atom(10, 20);
 print(a.f1());
 print(a.f2());
}

class Atom {
 int x;
 int y;
 int z = 100;

 Atom(this.x, this.y);

 int f1() {
  return x + y + z;
 }

 int f2() {
  //нужно указывать ключевое слово this или не нужно?
  return this.x + this.y + this.z;
 }
}
```

ответ

> 130 130

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы в рамках функции не работаете с другими значениями, передаваемыми в качестве параметров или объявляемых внутри функции, но с идентичным названием, то `f1()` от `f2()` отличатся у вас не будет.

То есть `this` вам нужен только как указатель на объект и однозначного указателя на поле конструкцией `this.value`, к которому вы применяете функцию:

```
a.f2(1, 2, 3);
int f2(int x, int y, int z) {
  //нужно указывать ключевое слово this или не нужно?
  return x + y + z;
}

#6
```

и

```
a.f2(1, 2, 3);
int f2(int x, int y, int z) {
   //нужно указывать ключевое слово this или не нужно?
   return this.x + x + this.y + y + this.z + z;
}

#136
```

Comment: Уважаемый Vladimir Afanasyev, Спасибо Вам большое!

Comment: @VladimirAfanasyev, поправьте пожалуйста код, глаза режет.

Comment: @MiT извиняюсь, при вставке форматирование съехало

Comment: @VladimirAfanasyev, спасибо!)